# Is it appropriate to include benchmarks in a CS research paper?

Tags: publications

I am planning to write a CS research paper on a new data structure I've discovered. Is it appropriate to include benchmarks comparing its performance for certain operations against that of a similar data structure, and include that in the paper? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly evaluate your data structure in some way, and that is one way to do it.

Look at what other papers introducing data structures use as benchmarks to get a feeling for what is expected. Using the same benchmarks as commonly used in the field helps with comparability between different papers.